# Testing render partial with nested partials in Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a helper that looks like so:

```
module ActivityFeedHelper
  def render_activity_feed(activities)
    render partial: 'activities/activity_feed', locals: { activities: activities }
  end
end
```

I'm writing a spec for the helper that looks like:

```
describe ActivityFeedHelper do
  describe '.render_activity_feed' do
    let(:activities) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:activity, 3) }

    it 'should render activity feed' do
      expect(render_activity_feed(activities)).to render_template(partial: 'activities/activity_feed')
    end
  end
end
```

But this is giving me the error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(render_activity_feed(activities)).to render_template(partial: 'activities/activity_feed')                                                                                                                          
       expecting partial <activities/activity_feed> but action rendered <["activities/_activity", "_activity", "activities/_activities", "_activities", "activities/_activity_feed", "_activity_feed"]>.                                      
       Expected {"activities/_activity"=>3, "_activity"=>3, "activities/_activities"=>1, "_activities"=>1, "activities/_activity_feed"=>1, "_activity_feed"=>1} to include "activities/activity_feed".
```

Presumably this is happening because the partial renders multiple sub-partials.

That said, how should I be testing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have felt into this trap too once. Your error means that you have to render template in this way:

```
expect(render_activity_feed(activities)).to render_template(partial: 'activities/_activity_feed')
```

Note the leading underscore in _activity_feed.

Comment: Yup - just discovered that before your post. Annoying! But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: It was all in your error message. Probably, majority of Rails errors can be solved by looking into the logs or other error output.